# How to make one of three TD in one TR of a Table resize itself to fill the remaining portions in HTML?

Tags: html

I made a Table in my page with height of 50px and width 100% and one row in that table, in which I inserted three TDs, first one of width 100px and third one of 50 px. I want the second one (the one which is in the middle) to resize itself to fill all the remaining portions in the middle, so that when browser window is resized, no scroll bar should come at down. I when directly wrote it's width=100% in style tag for this TD, it was fine with chrome but not with Firefox and when I wrote auto, it was fine with Firefox but not with chrome. Can someone please help?

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you may have done wrong

Comment: Well, I had kept the middle TD blank with specified height and width and was always working but did not work this time. I entered an invisible text in that TD, now work's done...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had kept the middle TD blank with specified height and width and was always working but did not work this time. I entered an invisible text in that TD, now work's done...

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to add anything on your center column. If left/right ones have a fixed width, the central one will automatically fill the remaining portion.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
td.left-col {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
td.center-col {
    background: yellow;
}
td.right-col {
    width: 50px;
    background: green
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left-col">Left</td>
        <td class="center-col">Left</td>
        <td class="right-col">Left</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com my bad, this jsFiddle account doesn't exists anymore. I made a new sample on my current account.